# Try to run torch but encounter INTERNAL ASSET FAILED

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, spyder, torchvision

Tried to uninstall and reinstall several different versions from the attempted solution in other threads.

But still encounter this issue of not getting the "supported version for reading".

Wonder if it is due to the compatibility of windows?

```
in __init__
    super(_open_zipfile_reader, self).__init__(torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(name_or_buffer))

RuntimeError: version_ <= kMaxSupportedFileFormatVersion INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED 
at ..\caffe2\serialize\inline_container.cc:132, please report a bug to PyTorch. 
Attempted to read a PyTorch file with version 3, but the maximum supported version for reading is 2. 
Your PyTorch installation may be too old. (init at ..\caffe2\serialize\inline_container.cc:132)
(no backtrace available)
```

windows 10 1909 (18363.1016)

CPU: AMD 4800HS

GPU: 1650Ti

Pytorch version:1.4.0+cu92

torchvision version: 0.5.0

Python version: 3.7

Compiler: Spyder(anaconda 3)

import syft

Comment: Did you use the latest version? it clearly says do so! if that didnt work, then `please report a bug to PyTorch.`

Comment: It still happens if I install the latest version.
Yeah, maybe there is a bug.